# choosing proper release of Ubuntu to install

Tags: system-installation

Before the latest release, I read that a beginner like myself should start by using old releases. Now I read that this latest release is more user friendly. Should I get it and jump in?

Answer (score 1):

You are always best off using the latest release available.  I'm not sure why someone would recommend older releases.  The latest ones are more likely to work correctly on your hardware and user friendliness is being improved with each release.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me it will not matter what version you use. How can you say that the oldest version is more user friendly and the latest is less? Since all the version is equally new to you it really doesn't matter :) Yes those who are using Ubuntu for a long time can say what new features are added to new releases and all.

My experience say Ubuntu has become more user friendly after time to time. New features are added after every release. Just chose any version of Ubuntu and get ready to enjoy it. I assure it you'll enjoy and learn very easily.